# How to code comma separated functions inside jQuery event, into CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm new to coffeescript, and while there is extensive information concerning the proper method of coding vanilla javascript in coffeescript, there is little information concerning how to code jQuery in coffeescript.

If someone could explain how to code the comma separated functions inside this jQuery hover event, as coffee script, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(".sprite-image.btn-rest").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-rest').addClass('btn-hover');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-hover').addClass('btn-rest');
        $(this).parent().prev().children('.sprite-image.btn-rest_before_activecurrent').removeClass('btn-rest_before_activecurrent').addClass('btn-rest');
        $(this).parent().prev('.sprite-image.nav_spacer_1-activecurrent').removeClass('nav_spacer_1-activecurrent').addClass('nav_spacer_1-rest');
    }
);
```

---

In response to the correct answer posted below by Larry Battle, I am posting the correction I made to Larry's original coffeescript *before* he made his correction.

```
$('.sprite-image.btn-rest').hover ->
    $(this).removeClass('btn-rest').addClass 'btn-hover'
, ->
    $(this).removeClass('btn-hover').addClass 'btn-rest'
    $(this).parent().prev().children('.sprite-image.btn-rest_before_activecurrent').removeClass('btn-rest_before_activecurrent').addClass 'btn-rest'
    $(this).parent().prev('.sprite-image.nav_spacer_1-activecurrent').removeClass('nav_spacer_1-activecurrent').addClass 'nav_spacer_1-rest'
```

I'm curious because this coffeescript produced the same result as his corrected answer. My question: Is one better than the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144191/coffeescript-method-chaining-with-function-arguments ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use js2coffee.org to check out what your javascript code would look like in coffeescript.

js2coffee.org translates your code to the following.

```
$(".sprite-image.btn-rest").hover (->
  $(this).removeClass("btn-rest").addClass "btn-hover"
), ->
  $(this).removeClass("btn-hover").addClass "btn-rest"
  $(this).parent().prev().children(".sprite-image.btn-rest_before_activecurrent").removeClass("btn-rest_before_activecurrent").addClass "btn-rest"
  $(this).parent().prev(".sprite-image.nav_spacer_1-activecurrent").removeClass("nav_spacer_1-activecurrent").addClass "nav_spacer_1-rest"
```

**Update**

js2coffee.org outputed incorrect code. Here's the correct translation.

```
$(".sprite-image.btn-rest").hover(
    ->
        $(this).removeClass("btn-rest").addClass "btn-hover"
    ,->
        $(this).removeClass("btn-hover").addClass "btn-rest"
        $(this).parent().prev().children(".sprite-image.btn-rest_before_activecurrent").removeClass("btn-rest_before_activecurrent").addClass "btn-rest"
        $(this).parent().prev(".sprite-image.nav_spacer_1-activecurrent").removeClass("nav_spacer_1-activecurrent").addClass "nav_spacer_1-rest"
)
```

Comment: ahhh it was those `( )` that I was missing. Will `js2coffee.org` translate jQuery as well as JavaScript? Thank you by the way!

Comment: I should mention that your answer isn't quite right. I tested it and those brackets should be left out. Once those are removed, it works perfectly. If you wouldn't mind, could you explain why coffeescript spits out the `return` for each function?

Comment: @stefmikhail jQuery is just a library; it doesn't change the language.  It just looks odd because `$` is a valid variable name in Javascript, and that's how jQuery is attached to the global scope.  Thus, `js2coffee` should have no problem with it.

Comment: @stefmikhail CoffeeScript automatically returns the last statement in a function.  This allows for short anonymous functions like `(a, b) -> a+b` to add two numbers.  To force it to return `undefined` (i.e. no return statement), you must put either an explicit `return` or an `undefined` at the end of a function.

Comment: @AaronDufour - I see, and thank you for the information. Concerning the `return` issue; I am not needing these functions to return anything, however I'm assuming there isn't any problem with returning the last value in each function, is there? I placed undefined on the last line of my coffeescript function (assuming that's correct), and what it did was spit out a `return` on the last line, unattached to any value. Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: @stefmikhail Yes, Coffeescript will always have a return statement.  However, `return;` will behave the same as not having a return statement (or a `return undefined;`, although I think Coffeescript avoids this for code length reasons).  jQuery usually ignores any return value from functions passed in, so its most likely fine either way.

Comment: @AaronDufour - Thanks again for the information. Much appreciated. I read the following issue at github outlining both people's ideas of possible methods to produce a 'return-less' function, as well as the reasoning behind having automatic returns. Worth a read. https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/899#issuecomment-590062

Comment: @LarryBattle - In response to your corrected answer, which indeed did output the proper javascript, I have posted my correction to your original post, underneath my original question. I'm hoping you can shed some light on why one might be better than the other, being that both output the same javascript. Thank you again!