# Coffeescript and jQuery chaining

Tags: coffeescript, chaining

I'm attempting this in coffeescript:

```
$( element ).mousedown( aFunction ).mouseup( anotherFunction );
```

I'm trying to work out a way to make use of indents so that something like the following will return what's about:

```
$ element
    .mousedown aFunction
    .mouseup anotherFunction
```

But to no avail, are there any recommendations for chaining in coffeescript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coffeescript - Method chaining with function arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144191/coffeescript-method-chaining-with-function-arguments)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sure you don't want to use parenthesis, but...

```
$("#element")
  .mousedown(aFunction)
  .mouseup(anotherFunction)
```

Compiles to

```
$("#element").mousedown(aFunction).mouseup(anotherFunction);
```

Comment: I think this is the correct solution at the moment, though this issue [has](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1495) [been](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1407) [raised](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1889) [many](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/944) [times](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2114) at [CoffeeScript's GitHub](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script), so some support for this kind of nesting might come in the future =D

Answer (score 1):

For all the other quick readers out there, here's the updated answer by [a paid nerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102704/a-paid-nerd) given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144191/coffeescript-method-chaining-with-function-arguments).

```
req = $.get('foo.html')
  .success (response) ->
    do_something()
  .error (response) ->
    do_something()
```

...compiles to:

```
var req;
req = $.get('foo.html').success(function(response) {
  return do_something();
}).error(function(response) {
  return do_something();
});
```

Looks like [mus is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) suggested it in a comment above as well.